# Bootstrap carousel indicator cycling issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've changed my Bootstrap carousel indicators from the radio buttons to small preview thumbnails, which has resulted in the thumbnails becoming all jumbled up when cycling.

Unfortunately, I don't understand Bootstrap's default carousel cycling at all, so I can't figure out how my active indicator thumbnail seems to displace the others.

If anyone can help me with this problem (and/or explain the default active indicator cycling), I would really appreciate the help!

HTML:

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#homeWineCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            <img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/blanc14.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#homeWineCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
            <img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/cabernet13.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#homeWineCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
            <img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/merlot13.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#homeWineCarousel" data-slide-to="3">
            <img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/syrah13.jpg">
        </li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <a href="blanc14.html"><img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/blanc14.jpg"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h3><a href="blanc14.html">Sauvignon Blanc 2014</a></h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="cabernet13.html"><img src="images/wine/cabernet13.jpg"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h3><a href="cabernet13.html">Cabernet Sauvignon 2013</a></h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="merlot13.html"><img src="images/wine/merlot13.jpg"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h3><a href="merlot13.html">Merlot 2013</a></h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="syrah13.html"><img src="images/wine/syrah13.jpg"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h3><a href="syrah13.html">Syrah 2013</a></h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homeWineCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homeWineCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators li img { 
    display: block; 
    width: 120px; height: auto; 
}
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 630px; 
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators .active { 
    position: relative;
    top: -230px;
    left: -75px;
}
.carousel-indicators li { 
    width: 80px; height: auto;
}
```

This is my first time using stack overflow, so if my question is unclear, or you need more information, please kindly let me know. I know my code's probably pretty messy and at least a little nonsensical - I'm a beginner and welcome any suggestions to help clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the `<li>` with only the image and place the attributes onto the image so it will look like this:

```
<img src="http://taybehwinery.com/images/wine/merlot13.jpg" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"/>
```

I have created JSFiddle with the following task working, please review and then if you have any questions afterwards I will be here to answer them.

http://jsfiddle.net/tfthum3t/